# How to fix "rigidbody2D is obsolete" error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, 2d-games

So I have been following a tutorial about 2d movement in Unity and the video run the code successfully. However, when I run the code, Unity said:
line

```
public Vector2 Velocity => rigidBody2D.velocity;
```

is error and it force me to use GetComponent instead.
So I follow the it and change the code to:

```
public Vector2 Velocity
    {
        get => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
        set => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = value;
    }
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your variant is legitimate way to go about it, tho
it is much more common to see the following:

```csharp
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public Vector2 Velocity;

void Start(){
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update(){
    rb2d.velocity = Velocity;
}
```

My only recommendation to you would be to get the reference in Start as well, since using GetComponent all the time is a bit wasteful performance vise.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>()` instead of the [obsolete](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-rigidbody2D.html) `Component.rigidbody2D` is good.

However storing the object returned instead of looking it up each time when you need to refer to it including during the call to your `Velocity` property is ***better***.  This will lead to better *performance*.

Change:

```
public Vector2 Velocity
{
    get => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
    set => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = value;
}
```

...to:

```
public Vector2 Velocity
{
    get => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
    set => GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = value;
}


private Rigidbody2D _rigidBody;

private Start()
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public Vector2 Velocity
{
    get => _rigidBody.velocity;
    set => _rigidBody.velocity = value;
}
```

Comment: It's totally fine if I put the _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); into Awake() right

Comment: @TranTrongTin sure.